# Combine two lists without duplicates prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a prolog homework that asks me to combine two lists together but without duplicates. For example `combine([a, b, c], [c, d, e], Result).`would give `Result = [a, b, c, d, e].`. But I'm getting `Result = [a, b, c, c, d, e].` instead.

My code looks like this:

```
combine([Head|Tail], Lst2, [Head|Result]) :- 
    combine(Tail, Lst2, Result).
```

How would I be able to remove the duplicates here in the same rule, not using helper functions?

Comment: are both lists ordered? can you assume that the lists themselves do not contain duplicates?

Comment: Yes, they are ordered and I don't think the lists themselves will contain any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each source list constitutes an *ordered set* (e.g., it is both ordered and unique), you could simply merge them and discard dupes when you encounter them. Something like this:

```
merge( []     , []     , []     ).   % the merger of two empty lists is the empty list.
merge( [X|Xs] , []     , [X|Xs] ).   % the merger of a non-empty list and an empty list is the non-empty list
merge( []     , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Ys] ).   % the merger of an empty list and a non-empty list is the non-empty list
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :- % to merge two non-empty lists
  X @< Y,                            % and the left item is less than the right item
  merge( Xs, [Y|Ys], Zs )            % take the left item and recurse down
  .                                  %
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- % to merge two non-empty lists
  X @> Y,                            % and the left item is greater than the right item
  merge( [X|Xs], Ys, Zs )            % take the right item and recurse down
  .                                  %
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :- % to merge two non-empty lists
  X == Y,                            % and the left and right items are equal
  merge( Xs, Ys, Zs )                % take either item, discard the other and recurse down
  .                                  % Easy!
```

And if you wanted to keep the duplicates, you'd just need to modify the last clause for the `==` condition to push both `X` and `Y` onto the merged list.

Comment: counterexample: merge([], [2,3], X).
your second and third clause are too restricted.

Comment: @tiffi: Fixed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using member.

```
combine(List1,List2,CombinedList):-
combine1(List1,List2,List), %Return List with items not in List2
append(List,List2,AppendedList), %Join List and List2
sort(AppendedList,CombinedList). %Sort the final List

combine1([],_,[]).
combine1([H|T],List2,[H|L]):-
    \+member(H,List2),
    combine1(T,List2,L).
combine1([H|T],List2,L):-
    member(H,List2),
    combine1(T,List2,L).
```

**Examples:**

```
?- combine([a,b,d],[c],CombinedList).
CombinedList = [a, b, c, d]
false

?- combine([a,d,e],[c,b],CombinedList).
CombinedList = [a, b, c, d, e]
false

?- combine([],[c,b,a],CombinedList).
CombinedList = [a, b, c]

?-combine([a,b,c],[c,d,e],CombinedList).
CombinedList = [a, b, c, d, e]
false
```